# Can't encode this string

Tags: base64

I'm doing a simple exercise where copy a base64 encoded cookie value, and then make a few changes and then re-encode, and then use the result to log into a site as admin.

I have the following encoded string:

```
Tzo0OiJVc2VyIjoyOntzOjg6InVzZXJuYW1lIjtzOjU6ImRhZHNhIjtzOjc6ImlzQWRtaW4iO2I6MDt9
```

I decode it like so:

```
$ echo Tzo0OiJVc2VyIjoyOntzOjg6InVzZXJuYW1lIjtzOjU6ImRhZHNhIjtzOjc6ImlzQWRtaW4iO2I6MDt9 | base64 --decode                       1 ⨯
O:4:"User":2:{s:8:"username";s:5:"dadsa";s:7:"isAdmin";b:0;}
```

I then make a small change in order to be able to log in as admin:

```
O:4:"User":2:{s:8:"username";s:5:"dadsa";s:7:"isAdmin";b:1;}
```

And them attempt to encode it again:

```
$ echo O:4:"User":2:{s:8:"username";s:5:"dadsa";s:7:"isAdmin";b:0;} | base64                                                    1 ⨯
zsh: parse error near `}'
```

Which gives me a parsing error.
I did this the other day, where this worked perfectly .

Why am i not able to encode this string?

Comment: This time, I don't think that one answers it, as it's more about values expanded from variables (etc), and doesn't seem to mention semicolons at all.

Comment: Semicolon is a special character, quoting would have solved it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo O:4:"User":2:{s:8:"username";s:5:"dadsa";s:7:"isAdmin";b:0;}
                                 ^           ^             ^   ^
```

The unquoted semicolons there work as command separators. Same as running `echo foo; ls -l` runs both `echo` and `ls` and not just `echo`. The `}` is a shell keyword, similarly to `if`, `then` or `fi`, and it's not in a syntactically correct place there, hence the error. (zsh doesn't accept even `echo }`, so there, it might be parsed as an operator, too.)

If you remove the `}`, you'll see "command not found" errors for `s:5:dadsa` etc.

You probably meant to quote the string:

```
echo 'O:4:"User":2:{s:8:"username";s:5:"dadsa";s:7:"isAdmin";b:0;}'
```

There's some lists of the shells' (plural) special characters in some Q&As here, e.g.
[What characters are required to be escaped in command line arguments?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/270977/what-characters-are-required-to-be-escaped-in-command-line-arguments/270979#270979) Also see [How to use a special character as a normal one in Unix shells?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/296141/170373) and [What is the difference between the "...", '...', $'...', and $"..." quotes in the shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/503013/170373)